# augmented reality coding to make sound

Tags: c#

i have coding to make augmented reality application. the function of the code it will make when the object 3d is touched , it will play sound of the obeject..

the code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DrumSound : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target1;
    public AudioSource suaratiger;

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
                if(hit.transform == target1){
                    suaratiger.audio.Play();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the error:

> Error CS1061: 'UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Play' and no extension method 'Play' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'UnityEngine.Component' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)

and

> Warning CS0618: 'UnityEngine.Material.Material(string)' is obsolete:
>   'Creating materials from shader source string will be removed in the
>   future. Use Shader assets instead.' (CS0618) (Assembly-CSharp)

what i mus to do ??

Comment: How is this related at all to Augmented Reality? This is plain Unity 3d.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that AudioSource does not contain a property called "audio", the proper way to play the source is by using AudioSource.Play(), as follows:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            if(hit.transform == target1)
                suaratiger.Play();
    }
}
```

Look at the documentation of [Audio Source](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html) for more information.

You should also note that, in the code you posted, you are never assigning something to suaratiger. Normally, you would get the AudioSource component in the Start method.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is just telling you you are missing a 'using' or an 'assembly' reference. I myself have not used vuforia, but I would suggest checking out the documentation about it. Is there maybe a 'using' refer called VuforiaBehaviourComponentFactory? Try putting using Vuforia or using VuforiaBehaviourComponentFactory at the top of your code. If it is not a 'using' reference, check if the built assembly(dll) is in the plugin folder in the inspector.